# Best way to drop multiple warehouses in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have too many warehouses to drop manually, it would be nice to do something like

```
drop warehouse like 'TEST_DW%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the statements with dynamic sql:

```
show warehouses like 'TEST_DW%';

select listagg('drop warehouse ' || "name" || ';', '\n') 
from table(result_scan(-1)) ;
```

Then cut and paste.